# How long does my game stay on sale?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

All of my games seem to stay on sale for the same amount of time before they're taken off the market. A game seems to stay on sale long enough to develop another game and have a single sales period of overlap before the previous game is removed from the market. Is this actually the case or are there particular thresholds that trigger a game to be removed from the market?

Is my current thought on this based on false observation based on making a bunch of games that sell a similar quantity of units each?

How long does my game stay on sale?

Comment: I've seen 20 weeks consistently. I'll keep watching though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on 20 small games, 10 medium games, 15 large games, and 1 MMO:

1. Small games sell for 12 weeks
2. Medium games sell for 18 weeks
3. Large games sell for 20 weeks

MMOs behave differently. Instead of leaving the market after a set period, they have maintenance costs and income each week. You can add expansion packs to an MMO to boost income, or you can take it off the market to cut your losses.